# Is using a dictionary of Char usefull?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I came up to a piece of code in a VB.Net application I have to maintain now.

It features a dictionary, declared like this (I simplified it):

```
Dim dataDico As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Char, Dictionary(Of String, String)))()
```

The key of the 2nd dictionary (Char) is **ALWAYS** the first char of the key of the 3rd dictionary (string).

It is initialized like this (again I simplified) :

```
If Not dataDico(string1).ContainsKey(string2(0)) Then
    dataDico(string1).Add(string2(0), New Dictionary(Of String, String))
End If
If Not dataDico(string1)(string2(0)).ContainsKey(string2) Then
    dataDico(string1)(string2(0)).Add(string2, "")
End If
```

And used in a similar fashion.

It seems to me that there is no point in using this 2nd dictionary with a Char as a key, when it's only a short entry for the 3rd dictionary. From my analysis there would be no impact on the code to remove this.

But is there any other reason I'm missing to do this? in terms of performances maybe?

Comment: Whether or not it is useful depends on what data the code gets from the dictionary and what it does with that data. At first glance it appears to be some kind of grouping mechanism. It will improve performance in the long run if the code is looking to get a collection of strings whose keys all start with the same character, however in exchange it will use a bit more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

It's always safe to check if it is the same value or not before we add it so we don't get an error or in this case a bad dictionary, so leaving it won't hurt knowing it's always the same. It will not affect the performance of your application.

Comment: All i can think of is whoever put it there, did it for a reason :) which makes me think it might not always be the same..

Answer (score 0):

Look for an operation which returns the inner dictionary by its first character (filters by the first character of the inner dictionary's key). Your current data structure not only allows for that selection with less code, but it would also be more performant to look up a hash than to enumerate your dictionary and filter.

```
dataDico("abc")("d"c) ' hash lookup
```

vs.

```
dataDico("abc").Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Key(0) = "d"c) ' enumeration and equality check
```